# Sales force App Integration ( .NET Development) & more detail for New bee

Tags: asp.net, web-services, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Yes Please note that I am very new to Salesforce , so please understand if I am not clear or not specific at anything.

I am new at Salesforce, and I need to make an App in ASP.NET which help clients/users to add hours/some field details at salesforce.

So what I need is, I need to make an web Application which will get details from Salesforce ( the details it self are custom object which I am explaining ahead) and do some calculations at my web App a& return back the result & display it at Salesforce.

So in summary :
1) Which way we can integrate .NET Web App at Salesforce
2) How we can make custom fields/page required which will be going to use at Web App & display at Salesforce page.

3) How we can make a custom UI & fields at Salesforce ?
4) How this field can be fetch/expose on submit at Web App?

** 5) Which API to use ? ( My case is we are planning that we will provide a way at Salesforce that a user can insert total hours, todays hours invested , remaining hours...based on these we can bill them. so for all of these calculations can be managed with which API ?)

6) Also how can I display the results & other things at Salesforce, I mean can I design page , if yes then which options I have to design page other then Apex??

.... there are many more things  I need to take care of & need to know . but as I am new at Salesforce so please guide me Tech Experts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather broad question, so I will give you the high-level steps of what needs to be done:

1) Create a Custom Object using Build; Create; Objects menu.

2) Save your enterprise WSDL under Build; Develop; API menu.  Typically you open the wsdl in a browser and save the web page as something.wsdl

3) In .NET create a web service reference using the enterprise WSDL you saved in a local file

4) You can write and read from to the custom object (or any Salesforce object) using the SF API.  To do so, you will need to write [SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm).

Once you have step 1,2,3 done, then you should look at the SF documentation on binding to the API and how to run insert and update statements in SOQL.  It is too much info for a SO question.

Comment: Thanks Sir, that's really helpful. I am implementing your described steps. I will contact you if I stuck anywhere. Also can you please provide me some links & sample App similar to my requirement so I can get the way faster? It will help me.

Comment: Here is a good example of connecting to teh API:  https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET  And this is where you want to start in terms of select and update in SF: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: Perfect links , thanks again SQLDBA , now I am wondering how can I display fields as per my custom Design at Salesforce and then if required any intera\nal or local calculations at the page at Salesforce and then how can I call my service /my App from there ? Sorry but at the documentations there are all detail but I need specific ones , so it makes me confused but you are helping me the way I can understand, I appreciate it.Thanks

Comment: ok I think I should further clear on my requirement  : What I need is 
the way that authorize user can enter a total hours for the task decided previously, then on daily basis the user will add some hours invested daily basis. and at third field it will show the automated field which will generated by some calculations for eg, remain hours , exceeded hours etc... SO

Comment: 1) First : make a page at salesforce where I can display these fields
( I know littlt about creating custom obj, and fields at salesforce.not much)

2) Then How can I create local functions or calculations with this fields?

3) How can I call and send data to my web app on Save button ?

4) And How can I retrieve the result & display it at the same page at SF ?

Comment: Sorry but I have work to do and can not commit that kind of time.  You will have to research it yourself.  That said, it sounds like you should not build a custom web application.  You should work directly within SF, including doing the calculation there.